# JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Добрый день!

Делаю такой простой запрос (с использованием JQuery):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',   
        url: adrServ.value + "/auth/login?username=" + login.value + "&password=" + password.value,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,   
        contentType:"application/json",                  
        //cache:false,
        success: function(data){var dat = data.AuthId;  localStorage["uid"] = dat;},
        error:function(){$.unblockUI();}
        });

alert(localStorage["uid"]);
```

Собственно в последней строчке выводится null. Если после этой строчки еще раз прописать вывод данных хранилища, то все ок. Не могу понять, что за ерунда такая. Может кто подскажет, может ошибка в коде? Работа с localStorage поддерживается (в тестируемых браузерах все норм.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня такое было когда ajax success еще не успел записать что-то куда-то, а я уже делал алерт. У тебя, походу, также...

Поиграйся с опцией async. Точно не помню, поможет ли она... И можно поставить задержку алерта, например, на 300 мс.  Но это не правильно.

Я бы сделал функцию, например:

```
GoodRequest() {
   alert(localStorage["uid"]);
}
```

и вызывал ее так:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',   
        url: adrServ.value + "/auth/login?username=" + login.value + "&password=" + password.value,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,   
        contentType:"application/json",                  
        //cache:false,
        success: function(data){var dat = data.AuthId;  localStorage["uid"] = dat; GoodRequest();},
        error:function(){$.unblockUI();}
        });
```

Comment: Если нужно просто посмотреть, что приходит, то можно alert и в success добавить и тогда точно он не будет срабатывать раньше.

Comment: Тоже склонялся к такой версии.
Добавил в запрос async: false и timeout: 30000. Вроде, полет нормальный.
Спасибо!

Comment: @MasterAlex, Я написал, если нужно отделить одну логику от другой, а так, то можно весь код написать в success, и должно быть good)

Comment: Лучше использовать промисы http://api.jquery.com/promise/#promise1

Comment: Ок. Спасибо, надо будет попробовать.