# После загрузки через Ajax с первого раза не находит элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, такая вот проблемка. Я загружаю контент через ajax. И мне после загрузки контента нужно с ним работать в плане jquery. Я попробовал просто выводить класс блока, который загружается через ajax и получается так, что скрипт отрабатывает только со второго раз, первый раз - undefined.

Здесь html index-файла:

```
<ul>
   <li><span rel="a">Link a</span></li>
   <li><span rel="b">Link b</span></li>
</ul>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Здесь html подгружаемых файлов:

```
<div class="a">text a</div>
```

или

```
<div class="b">text b</div>
```

Вот мой код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $(document).on('click', 'li span', function () {

       // load content start
       var linkHref = $(this).attr('rel');       
       $('.content').load(linkHref + '.html');
       // load contetn end

       var e =  '.content div';

       console.log($(e).attr('class'));

   });

});
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356787/jquery-ajax/356792#356792

Мой ответ на етот вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $('.content').load(linkHref + '.html');
> // load contetn end
> ```

Никакой это не конец загрузки. Загрузка происходит асинхронно.

> ```
> var e =  '.content div';
>   console.log($(e).attr('class'));
> ```

А это происходит сразу, т. е. заведомо до того, как загрузка будет выполнена.

Надо так:

```
$('.content').load(linkHref + '.html', function() {
  var e =  '.content div';
  console.log($(e).attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое